# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: twoDimensionArr.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get an array, sent from the backend the use it's values but for a reason, I get this error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: twoDimensionArr.map is not a function`.

Here is the fetch request:

```
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  const [dates, setDates] = React.useState(null);
  const [coinValue, setCoinValue] = React.useState(null);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/bitcoin")
      .then((res) => res.json()) 
      .then((data) => {

        const twoDimensionArr = data;
        setData(twoDimensionArr);               
        setDates(twoDimensionArr.map(item => item[0]));    
        setCoinValue(twoDimensionArr.map(item => item[1]));
   })
  }, []);
```

any idea what makes the problem? and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: It looks like your `data` is null or your array is placed in `data` property. Could you write `console.log(data)` and say what it has?

Comment: `const twoDimensionArr = data || [];` Try this

Comment: It's kind of a dumb question, I'm just new to the language and visual code, where am I supposed to see the log, because it's not showing in the terminal

Comment: @Kapobajza the problem is still probleming );

Comment: Then the `data` that you receive is maybe an object. Try to `console.log` it like @StepUp said. `console.log(data)` and it should show up in your browser inspector > console tab

Comment: @Kapobajza I think that might be the problem.
it shows:
   {message: Array(366)}
message: (366) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2) ,…]
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: `const twoDimensionArr = data.message;`

Comment: IT WORKEDDDD, thank you I love you so muchhhhhhhhh